# how can we give conditions on listview item ..when we want to match the String?

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on listview. I have one activity type menu.java, where items are coming from server in listview e.g pizza, pasta, lasagna etc.

If I click listview item pizza or pasta then on next activity there is another listview contains items which is related to pizza like bianca pizza or cheese pizza etc and so on. If I click cheese pizza or bianca pizza item of listView, the alert dialog box will appear where the customer can make choices. For example for pasta a alertbox will appear as pizza but this time alertbox has to be different.

My problem is that I can't make condition to display distinct alertbox ( e.g alertbox1 for item1 or alertbox2 for item2 ) for each item of listView

I can't make switch case also because it's not a direct condition, I have to make changes in my SUBMENU activity and the main List on Typemenu activity.

Here is my SubMenu Activity where in listview click item alertbox will appear.

I tried putting if condition but its not invoking my alertbox :

```
public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status="";
    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;
    String _stringVal;

    final int Pizza = 0; //should be equal to the index in your array.
    final int Pasta = 1;
    final int Lasagna = 2;
    final int Salad =3 ;
    final int Breakfast = 4;
    final int Beverages= 5;
    final int Soup = 6;

    final int SpecialOffer =7;



    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.....com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {


                if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Bianca Pizza")||listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Cheese Pizza"))
                {
                    final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                    customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                    customDialog.setView(dialogView);
                    final Spinner crust, adds;
                    // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button
                    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(dialogView.getContext());
                    final ImageView desimage = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
                    // final  CircleImageView desimage =(CircleImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
                    imageLoader.DisplayImage(arraylist.get(position).get("image"), desimage);
                    final TextView heading = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h1);
                    heading.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("name"));
                    final EditText spins = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinst);
                    heading.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("name"));
                    final String hed = heading.getText().toString();
                    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);
                    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.adson);
                    final ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    final ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    final String[] _spvalue1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crust_array);
                    final String[] _spvalue2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AddsOn_array);
                    for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue1.length; i++) {
                        alspinner1.add(_spvalue1[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue2.length; i++) {
                        alspinner2.add(_spvalue2[i]);
                    }
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner1);
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner2);
                    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    final String spinner2Selection = alspinner2.get(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, spinner2Selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Button _decrease = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
                    Button _increase = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);
                    final TextView _value = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(value);
                    i = Integer.parseInt(_value.getText().toString());
                    _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //String _stringVal;
                            Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                            if (i > 0) {
                                i = i - 1;
                                _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                                _value.setText(_stringVal);

                                Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "" + _stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Log.d("src", "Value can't be less than 0");
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    _increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                            i = i + 1;
                            _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                            _value.setText(_stringVal);
                            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "" + _stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });


                    Button altok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alrtok);
                    altok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
                            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            pDialog.show();
                            final String spli = spins.getText().toString();
                            final RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgrp1);
                            final String rval1;
                            final RadioButton rbtn;
                            final int selectedId = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbtn = (RadioButton) dialogView.findViewById(selectedId);
                            rval1 = rbtn.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, rval1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, spli, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                                    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                                // Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                startActivity(new Intent(SubMenu.this, AddToCart.class));

                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "Please Give Full Information!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    },

                                    new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }) {

                                @Override
                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    params.put("dish_name", hed);
                                    params.put("type", rval1);
                                    params.put("crust", alspinner1.get(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                                    params.put("addson", alspinner2.get(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                                    params.put("quantity", _stringVal);
                                    params.put("special_instruction", spli);

                                    return params;
                                }
                            };

                            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SubMenu.this);
                            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                        }
                    });

                    final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
                    cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            customDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    final ImageButton crssbtn = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                    crssbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            customDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    customDialog.show();

                }

                 else if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Pasta"))

                {
                    final AlertDialog customDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                    customDialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    final LayoutInflater inflater1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogView1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.popup1, null);
                    customDialog1.setView(dialogView1);
                    final Button cncl1 = (Button) dialogView1.findViewById(R.id.canc1);
                    cncl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            customDialog1.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    final ImageButton crssbtn1 = (ImageButton) dialogView1.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1);
                    crssbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            customDialog1.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    customDialog1.show();
                }

                else if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Lasagna"))

                {
                    final AlertDialog customDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                    customDialog2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    final LayoutInflater inflater2 = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.popup2, null);
                    customDialog2.setView(dialogView2);
                    final Button cncl2 = (Button) dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.canc2);
                    cncl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            customDialog2.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    final ImageButton crssbtn2 = (ImageButton) dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel2);
                    crssbtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            customDialog2.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    customDialog2.show();
            }


                else if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Salad"))

                {
                final AlertDialog customDialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                customDialog3.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                final LayoutInflater inflater3 = getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.popup3, null);
                customDialog3.setView(dialogView3);
                final Button cncl3 = (Button) dialogView3.findViewById(R.id.canc3);
                cncl3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        customDialog3.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                final ImageButton crssbtn3 = (ImageButton) dialogView3.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel3);
                crssbtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        customDialog3.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                customDialog3.show();
            }

                else if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Breakfast"))

                {
                final AlertDialog customDialog4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                customDialog4.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                final LayoutInflater inflater4 = getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView4 = inflater4.inflate(R.layout.popup4, null);
                customDialog4.setView(dialogView4);
                final Button cncl4 = (Button) dialogView4.findViewById(R.id.canc4);
                cncl4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        customDialog4.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                final ImageButton crssbtn4 = (ImageButton) dialogView4.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel3);
                crssbtn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        customDialog4.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                customDialog4.show();
            }


                else if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Beverages"))

                {
                    final AlertDialog customDialog5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                    customDialog5.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    final LayoutInflater inflater5 = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogView5 = inflater5.inflate(R.layout.popup5, null);
                    customDialog5.setView(dialogView5);
                    final Button cncl5 = (Button) dialogView5.findViewById(R.id.canc5);
                    cncl5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            customDialog5.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    final ImageButton crssbtn5 = (ImageButton) dialogView5.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel5);
                    crssbtn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            customDialog5.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    customDialog5.show();

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {
            //  Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"The planet is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

i have a different-2 layout for diffrent alertbox. here i m just conditioning first listview conditions ...

the the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.zeba.broccoli, PID: 28504
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.zeba.broccoli.SubMenu$DownloadJSON.onItemClick(SubMenu.java:161)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1532)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3700)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5684)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199
```

Comment: Move your `listView` and viewRelated codes to main class. Make a global ArrayList , populate that on asyncTask then set adapter on main class and so on.

and if you want to invoke view related work from background thread then use runOnUIThread(new Runnable) method

Comment: that will b big problm...so much of code tht works fine

Comment: see i am getting the listview item n everything but only if i put condition thn it creates null value

Comment: i just need to match my condition with value given in listview...thn it invokes alertbox..but here thts nt happening

Comment: can u help me through coding...i stuck to this fr whole day

Comment: there is too much code to read. can you please specify which condition and where its creating problem

Comment: if ( listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Bianca Pizza")||listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Cheese Pizza"))
       here its not taking valur from list...

Comment: here i am having item from server in listview but if i put condition thr its not  taking value

Comment: try this   `if ( parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Bian‌​ca Pizza")|| parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equ‌​als("Cheese Pizza"))`

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: its shows null pointer exception...dont know y?